# In Google Sheets, how do I pad a table of dated values with dates where nothing changed?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I've got a table with data like this showing chronological dates when a balance value changed:

```
----Table 1----
Date    Balance
1/1/19  0
1/3/19  2,000.00
1/6/19  2,159.81
```

I also added an adjacent column of calendar dates that has every single day on the calendar listed. I'm trying to come up with a formula for an additional "Balance" column that somehow uses the data from my first table to automatically "fill in" the balance values of my new table, repeating the values when they don't change:

```
----Table 2----
Date    Balance
1/1/19  0
1/2/19  0
1/3/19  2,000.00
1/4/19  2,000.00
1/5/19  2,000.00
1/6/19  2,159.81
1/7/19  2,159.81
1/8/19  2,159.81
```

I've tried various things like =MATCH and =VLOOKUP but nothing I try is coming close to making this work, and I am worried I will have to enter these manually. Is there a formula that can do this automatically?

Comment: VLOOKUP is the correct formula what is the formula you tried that failed.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:A,1), but this immediately failed.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(E2,$A:$B,2,TRUE)`

Comment: That did it! The answer below also works, but it auto-fills the cells below, instead of requiring a formula in each cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `Sheets` you may try:

```
=index(xlookup(D2:D,A:A,B:B,,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I set up my sheet exactly like this and I just get a cell reference error.

Comment: Oh, whoops! I thought every cell had to have that formula, and I repeated the formula down and it was overwriting the value of the cell below. It actually worked!